# Move down one cell with keyboard in Libreoffice Calc

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, libreoffice-calc

The cursor is on Cell E2. I would like it to be on Cell E3.

Pressing <kbd>▼</kbd> scrolls the sheet.

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>▼</kbd> jumps to oblivion.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>▼</kbd> selects.

Surely there's a way to do this?

Comment: *Pressing Down scrolls the sheet* - perhaps you didn’t notice that you pressed the [**ScrollLock button**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scroll_Lock)? Please try changing [**Tools - Options - LibreOffice Calc - General - Input settings - Press Enter to move selection**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/optionen/01060300.html) to **Down** and use `Enter` to move between cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JohnSUN's comment is correct: I needed to unpress ScrollLock. I must note, however, I can't readily see any indicators to see its pressed as my laptop doesn't have a Scroll Lock key or LED.

This [article](https://support.lenovo.com/mo/en/solutions/ht503647-thinkpad-keyboard-function-fn-keys-for-2017-thinkpad-systems-windows-10) from Lenovo support however says

> Fn + K: This key combination has the same function as the ScrLK or Scroll Lock key on a conventional external keyboard.

This is valid for all ThinkPads. For other systems, see this [Microsoft article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-off-scroll-lock-a78492cc-c124-4782-a38b-df46669520e0):

> click Start > Settings > Ease of Access > Keyboard, Click the On Screen Keyboard button to turn it on.

or

> To quickly open the On-screen Keyboard in Windows 10, click the Windows button. Begin typing On-Screen Keyboard which will appear in the search entry box. Under Search, which will appear as a list above the search box, click the On-Screen Keyboard search result. When the on-screen keyboard appears, click the ScrLk button.

An open source indicator for Windows for the Lock keys can be found at https://github.com/jonaskohl/CapsLockIndicator